# Java data structure that retains order, does not allow duplicates, and allows removal and insertion at start and end

Tags: java, collections

Is there a Java data structure that:

- does not allow duplicates
- retains insertion order
- allows removal and insertion at either the start or end of the collection

There is `LinkedHashSet`, but it only allows `remove(object)`, `add(object)` as per `Set`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LinkedHashSet will allow removal of the first element, just do

```
Iterator iter = linkedHashSet.iterator();
if(iter.next()) {
   iter.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Java 21, `LinkedHashSet` meets the stated requirements.

`LinkedHashSet` was updated to have [`addFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html#addFirst(E)), [`addLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html#addLast(E)), [`removeFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html#removeFirst()), and [`removeLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html#removeLast()) methods.  This, when combined with the previously existing capabilities of `LinkedHashSet`, meets the stated requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to give up a little performance for no duplicates, you can always extend [`ArrayDeque`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) and override all the methods that insert into the collection to see if the element already exists.

Comment: I only need removal/insertion at one end, doesn't matter which. Updated question to remove the ambiguity somewhat.